# recursion inside a for loop, iterations changes by factors when base case changes

Tags: java, loops, recursion

I am fairly new to Java. I was learning recursion and was reading through this code to see if I could trace it.

In the base case, when I change the `k` value to 1 from 0, the number of iterations changes by a factor of 9.

I tried to trace it with some sysouts, and still don't understand it. I do understand that this is recursion within a for loop. I understand the recursion output without the for loop, but once it's added back in, I can't trace why it recalls itself when the base case goes equals 0.

Given the initial call of `k = 2`, why does it jump from 9 to 81 when the base condition changes from 1 to 0?

I spent hours trying to understand it.

The code is as below:

```
public class recurforloop { 

    public static void printrecurforloop(int number,  int k) { 
//when I change the value of  k == 1, the iterations reduces from 81 to 9
        if (k == 0) { 
            System.out.println(number); 
        } 

        for (int i = ( 1); i < 10; i++) { 
            printrecurforloop(number * 10 + i, k - 1); 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        printrecurforloop(0, 2); 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Your method only takes 2 parameters, but you are passing 3 on the recursive call. Please post your actual code.

Comment: Also, I am surprised you say this code terminates after some number of iterations: you don't stop the recursion when `k == 0`, but rather keep on recursing indefinitely.

Comment: thanks @Andy Turner. I have now updated the code. Yes, it originally had 3 parameters, but when I was trying to understand it , I reduced it to 2 parameters,  and while I was trying to  remove all my sysouts in between  I missed that part.   Yes , so when k==0, it goes from 11 to 99, but when k==1, it does from 1 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

It is changing by a factor of 9 because each time the printrecurforloopmethod is being called it is being called 9 times inside the for-loop until k=0.

Comment: thanks @Aaron Rotem. I like how you summarized it.  what I don't understand is why does it only call itself only 9 times until k ==1.  how does it know to go again 9 times 9 times for when k==0.

Comment: When k=0, it stops the recursive call.  So imagine a nested for loop instead of a recursive method inside of a for loop, because in this case they are essentially doing the same thing.  The for loop repeats itself until the base case is called then it exits that loop and calls the inner loop again.  That process repeats until the base condition of the outer loop is met.In your case, the outer loop will execute 9 times and each of those times the recursive method calls itself 9 times.

Comment: thanks @Aaron Rotem. That helps me; to think of it as a nested for loop ; and that the recursive calls itself again 9 times for when k==0. thanks